# How to set alignment properly to file?

Tags: c++, file, alignment

I am adding a little bit of alignment to file . I add name, say having size 20, to file and it messes up all my alignment! 
Do you know how to set width to file without using escape characters?

The following code is just a part of student-related functions-

```
void save()
{
    FILE* fp;
    fp = fopen("Student.txt", "w");
fprintf(fp,"Roll No\tName\t\t\t\tPaper 1\tPaper 2\tPaper 3\tTotal  \tGrade\n");
    for(int i = 0; i < time; ++i)
    {
        fprintf(fp, "%d\t%s\t   \t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%c\n", info[i].rollNo, info[i].name,info[i].p1, info[i].p2, info[i].p3, info[i].total, info[i].grade);
    }
    cout << "Successfully written to file!" << endl;
    fclose(fp);
    getch();
    menu();
}
```

Thank you!!1

Comment: Do you dislike C++ features such as strings and output streams?

Comment: @Beta I don't know all about C++. So you know.

Comment: Could you show us a couple of output lines, as you wish them to appear in the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your question, you might wanna take a look at the [setw](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iomanip/setw/) and [setfill](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iomanip/setfill/)  functions.